# Elasticpress cannot connect to remote Elasticsearch on Digitalocean server

Tags: wordpress, elasticsearch, digital-ocean

I have a droplet on DigitalOcean with elasticsearch properly running, I have another installation (on a different server) of wordpress with elasticpress that keeps sending this error: **There is a problem with connecting to your Elasticsearch host. ElasticPress can try your host again, or you may need to change your settings.** I'm using the IPv4 of the digitalocean droplet and port 9200 in the WP-config file, to define EP_HOST. Do I need a proxy server or what is missing? I've followed many tutorials with no success.

Comment: have you specified IP of your server on `network.host` in `elasticsearch.yml` file ?

Comment: @ashish As you said, I forgot to specify the `network.host`, but now I have it and still, I'm unable to connect my ElasticPress

Comment: make your `network.host: 0.0.0.0`

Comment: I tried that, but nope, I followed up a "tutorial" they provided in their page, where I configured the `network.host: 0.0.0.0`, I even added to firewall a rule allowing my remote IP and all that, but no success.